# Pausing a scene and run another

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible, in cocos2d-iphone, to "freeze" your scene, and run different scene (say, a pause scene), and when you are done with this scene, you can change back to the original scene and resume it just fine? I guess it is possible, someone once told me I could stack scenes or something in the CCDirector, but I did not quite understand what methods are necessary.

Comment: You could also pause the game **layer** and show another layer on top which acts as the pause layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [what you're looking for](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_director.html#a548727f4d1521265d32abc2916f72f55):

```
// show the pause scene
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:pauseScene];
...
// return back to the game scene
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
```

Keep in mind that the original scene remains in memory, so ideally the pushed scene should be lightweight, memory-wise.

The popScene transition can not be animated with CCSceneTransition. Cocos2D 2.0 is supposed to fix that, but the planned improvement is not yet available.

Comment: Thanks! So when I am done with the pause scene, what should I do to properly dispose of it and go back to the game scene?

Comment: you just call popScene to dismiss the most recently pushed scene